# How to add labels to graticule?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps

I am trying to build with d3.js (just started a couple of days ago) an interactive (zooming+panning) sky map using the Aitoff-Hammer projection in order to display astronomical objects.

I successfully got my first map (here:

```
    `http://jsfiddle.net/syf4r6zw/`
```

), which is great.

However, I would like to add labels to the graticule (a bit like this: http://tdc-www.harvard.edu/wcstools/projections/ait.gif). Does someone know how to do it?

Thanks for your help!
Arnaud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got something to work ; see here:

```
'http://jsfiddle.net/syf4r6zw/2/
```

(based on an idea posted here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2259)

The core of the labeling is in the function labelGraticule(). Please note that this is for an astronomical use (peculiar coordinates: Right Ascension/Declination).

Arnaud